# Adsense Invalid Earning

Tags: adsense

I have several website running and I can't seem to find which site is generating the invalid earning. On the reports it only shows the total invalid earning.
Is there a way to view for individual websites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is not. However 90% is users clicking on ads that did not want too, or users ending up with a bad experience. Go over your ads one by one and make sure that users do not accidentally click on your ads. This way you should not have any invalid earnings.